# Why can't I put my event handler on the class declaration for my Dijit widget?

Tags: javascript, dojo

If I define my click handler when instantiating my widget:

```
new W2({onClick: a_function});
```

during `postMixinProperies` or during `postCreate`:

```
dojo.declare("W2", [W1], {
    postMixInProperties: function(){
        this.onClick= a_function;
    }
});
```

or via the one of the declarative approaches

```
<div data-dojo-type="W2">
    <script
        type="dojo/connect"
        data-dojo-event="onClick">
        a_function.call(this);
    </script>
</div>
```

dojo does its magic and makes it so the `onclick` event on the domNode triggers my `onClick` handler.

**However**, if I place the `onClick` definition on the class declaration the connection apparently gets broken:

```
dojo.declare("W2", [W1], {
    onClick: a_function
});
```

It is still possible to call `my_widget.onClick` directly, it isn't called automatically after `onclick` events anymore.

*Why is this happening, is this normal and what is the "standard way" for defining event handlers for my widget classes?*

---

**edit:** code for W1:

```
dojo.declare("W1", [dijit._Widget, dijit._Templated], {
    label: 'defaultLabel',
    templateString: '<div>${label}</div>' 
});
```

Comment: Can you show the code for W1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define the attach event in a templated widget to connect DOM events to functions.

Try doing someting like:

```
dojo.declare("W1", [dijit._Widget, dijit._Templated], {
    label: 'defaultLabel'
    , templateString: "<div data-dojo-attach-event='onclick: onClick'>${label}</div>"
});
```

You can then put onClick in your class declaration and it will be connected to the DOM event.

```
dojo.declare("W2", [W1], {
    onClick: a_function
});
```

If the widget is not templated and the super class has already connected the DOM event to a function named onClick, then setting the onClick function will just work.

```
dojo.declare("W1", [dijit._Widget, dijit.form.Button], {
    label: 'defaultLabel'
});
```

If the widget is not templated and the super class has not connected the DOM event to a function, then you need to make that connection.

```
dojo.declare("W1", [dijit._Widget], {
    label: 'defaultLabel'
    , postCreate: function () {
        this.inherited(arguments);
        dojo.create('div', {innerHTML: 'defaultLabel'}, this.domNode)
        this.connect(this.domNode, "onclick", "onClick");
    }
});
```

Comment: Interesting. And what should I do if my widget is not templated?

Comment: Updated answer to include non templated widget examples.

Comment: Great, this lines up perfectly with the tests I had made to try to understand this.